# How can I find vulnerabilities in this code?

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

In this code there are 4 vulnerable points. Does anyone know how to find them?

```
    char *alloc_and_copy(char *dst,char src[], unsigned int nbcells) {
        unsigned char size;
        size = nbcells;
        dst = (int*)malloc(size);
        strcpy(dst, src);
        return dst;
    }

    int main() {
        char t1[256];
        char *t2;
        scanf("%s", t1);
        t2 = *alloc_and_copy(t2, t1, 256);
        sprintf("%s", t2);
        free(t2);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think? You even tagged the question as "buffer-overflow".

Comment: Only 4? I feel like that's on the low side. Turning on compiler warnings should help with a number of the issues.

Comment: 1) Buffer-overflow 2) Segmentation 3) Input validation 4) unsigned int (4byte) to unsigned char(1byte)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find vulnerabilities in this code?

With experience, a good set of compiler options, a static source code analyzer, a dynamic analyzer, ... anything you know how to use. If you don't know how to use such, I'm afraid that you have to learn.

You can find the worst problems by raising the warning level of your compiler to the max and even give option like `-pedantic` for GCC. The same applies to the analyzers of which the static kind is quite simple to use.

Then you can build tables of possible control and data flows. For instance `scanf()` can do anything of these:

1. Read nothing at all into `t1` leaving it completely uninitialized, perhaps because of I/O errors.
2. Read a zero length string; just one character, `'\0'`, will be stored in `t1`.
3. Read anything between the previous and the next length.
4. Read a string filling `t1` up to the last character, but not overflowing it.
5. Read a string longer than `t1` provides space for.
6. Read a string very much longer than `t1` provides space for.

Some of these might have the same effect, beware. Then think about what will happen further down the control flow.

Do this for every function call, every assignment, and every instruction. Some instructions are simple and don't do any harm, others are quite tricky. You have to read the documentation of the functions carefully, and the C standard, may be more than one version of it.

There are some traps to distract you from the real errors, too.

> Does anyone know how to find them?

Yes, a lot of people know this.

Well, you didn't ask for the vulnerabilities. And from your comment you didn't want to, perfect. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood the question. I didn't want anyone to find the vulgarity in the code, (code extracted from a university exam track) but to help me understand what to look for and what clues we could suggest that in that line of code there could be vulnerability.

Comment: @VincenzoFreddoLaForgia This sounds like "given arbitrary code, how do I know if there are bugs?" What form do you believe a correct answer would take? The answer, as here, is "use compiler warnings, then a static analyzer, then review the code." Do you believe a proper answer would say something else? If your deeper point is "C is hard to get right," yes, that is correct. Decades of program language research have gone into replacing C with things easier to get right. Yet still, we often work in C. And it's hard.